# Browsers won't load pages get XML interpreter error in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, xml

When I run Mozilla Firefox on Windows 8.1 webpages won't load and I sometimes get an XML interpretation error. It says unexpected interpreter status and gives a link to a file called netError.xhtml I post the link again if I see it but it doesn't show up atm.

So I thought I test IE on winfows 8.1 and I get the same problem except I don't get any error message. Some sites seems to work even it is a little bit slow. Other sites don't work at all like Google.

A common problem is that when I try to log in to any site the word connection interrupted are written in the Firefox window. So main sites can work but if I click on a link to log in to the sites even the log in link prints out connection interrupted.

I also have a suspicious block by the comodo firewall. C:\Program Files\Synaptics\SynTPEnh.exe which request memory access to C:\Program Files\COMODO\COMODO Internet Security\cis.exe
And to C:\Program Files\COMODO\COMODO Internet Security\cistray.exe

I inactivated Comodo but no difference.

How do I fix this?

I run a multiboot system with Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint 17.1.

Comment: Contact web server admin and tell him/her to correct the page

Comment: I have no problem with the sites and browsing at all from other devices. I have never experienced this problem before.

Comment: Do you get this error on one particular site?

Comment: No it's on many sites and links.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the entire error

Comment: I don't get the error message now but all the problems are same as before.